# How to replace "Tab" sign and multiple spaces so that they show correctly in HTML mail body

Tags: html, vb.net, outlook

I am looking for a way to replace `RichTextBox` multiple spaces and tabs with html characters so that they are shown correctly in Outlook `.HTML` mail body.

I tried using that for tabs:

```
msg = msg.Replace(vbTab, "<td>")
```

But it does not work. I do now know what to do for multiple spaces - I do not find any <> code to use in this code:

```
msg = msg.Replace("  ", "<what to put here?>")
```

All ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML entity for space is `&nbsp;` and the entity for tab is `&emsp;`.

Here is how you would apply it to your RichTextBox:

```vb
Dim message = MyRichTextBox.Text.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;").Replace(ControlChars.Tab, "&emsp;")
```